# table join or not when ON statement false?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a sql query (Part of a procedure) like this:-

```
DECLARE ab INT;
SET ab = 1;
SELECT * FROM `table1` LEFT OUTER JOIN
`table2` ON
`table1`.`columnfromtable1`=`table2`.`columnfromtable2` AND ab=0;
```

My question is 'what is the sql engine's first job?'

1. Join these tables
2. executing `ON` clause and desire to update `NULL` values for columns

Or

1. executing `ON` clause
2. Desire to skip `JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you want to know if an index is used or how a query is performed you should use the [explain syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

When EXPLAIN is used with an explainable statement, MySQL displays information from the optimizer about the statement execution plan.

And this is valid for any query, not only this one.

You only need to understand the [EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html).